# Inline documentation not working in IntelliJ IDEA 14 with AOSP source files

Tags: intellij-idea, android-source, cyanogenmod

I am working with the source code for Cyanogenmod 12.1 in IntelliJ IDEA 14.1. I initially used the [idegen.sh](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/android-5.1.0_r1/tools/idegen/README) tool to generate an android.ipr IDEA project file. After opening this .ipr file and letting IDEA scan and index everything, I noticed there is no inline documentation of any kind, for either Android classes or Java classes such as String.

[image]

IDEA seems to be trying to draw documentation from `external/chromium_org/third_party/libaddressinput/src/java/android.jar`. I'm interested in why it's chosen this android.jar of all places to try and source documentation and declarations from. Goto Declaration brings me to the decompiled bytecode from this .jar as well.

Ideally, I would like regular inline documentation as in a normal Android project. I think if the project SDK is changed to an Android one or extra documentation paths are added, this can be done, but I am holding off on acting until I know what the best option is in case it rescans and reindexes everything (which took over an hour the first time round), and still does not work.

The project SDK is OpenJDK 7 but with all .jars removed from the classpath, as advised [here](https://shuhaowu.com/blog/setting_up_intellij_with_aosp_development.html). On the Documentations tab of the SDK, the only path is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/docs/api`.

Comment: Maybe this comment is not related with question? May i ask, how you can import entire cyanogen? i followed official instruction and get .ipr then open intellij. After indexing, apps under the package folder has errors because of R. class is not initiated. Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: @reigeki Assuming you've already done a build of Cyanogenmod at least once, marking `out/target/common/R` as a 'Source' directory might solve your problem (as detailed [here](https://shuhaowu.com/blog/setting_up_intellij_with_aosp_development.html))

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to get inline documentation working, although I still don't know why documentation was being attempted to be sourced from `external/chromium_org/third_party/libaddressinput/src/java/android.jar` originally.

I did 'Goto Declaration' on some occurrence of `String`, though I don't think the specific occurrence or class was important, it could have been an occurrence of `Activity` or any other class. This then opened the decompiled bytecode of the `String` class as from within `external/chromium_org/third_party/libaddressinput/src/java/android.jar`. There was a bar at the top of the tab, with a 'Choose Sources' link at its rightmost, I clicked this and navigated to and chose `frameworks/base/core/java`, the location of Android sources.

IDEA started rescanning, and after finishing there was documentation for Android classes, but still not for standard Java classes (like `String`). So I did the above again (with some other arbitrary Java class occurrence which still wasn't showing inline documentation), but this time specified `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/src.zip`, the location of JDK sources on my machine, when I clicked 'Choose Sources'. After this, both Java and Android classes were showing inline documentation.